# How to write to second element of a struct array? In C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
struct people
{
    char *name;
    char *surname;
} *human;
human = malloc(10*sizeof(struct people));
```

Hello everyone. I am trying to acccess elements of this struct array but I think I am doing it wrong.
I tried this to access second element's name string
    `human[1].name;`
And when it didn't worked I tried this
    `human[1.sizeof(struct people)].name;`
Thanks in advance

Comment: `human[1].name` should work, how exactly is it not working? Do you get a compiler error, or segfault..?

Comment: So human[1].name is not wrong thanks.

Comment: *"When it didn't work..."* What was the result?  Compiler-error?  Run-time crash?  Results different than expected?  **You must describe what happened when it "didn't work"**

Comment: Well in the end i put a loop that prints all elements.

Comment: it only printed 7th element over and over with character mistakes.

Comment: > it only printed 7th element over and over with character mistakes.
That suggests that perhaps you are not filling the array correctly....

Comment: you should post the printing code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the struct and the array that wiill be simpler

```
typedef struct people
{
    char *name;
    char *surname;
} people;

people  * human=malloc(10*sizeof(struct people));

humam[0].name=malloc((10+1)*sizeof(char));

strcpy(human[0].name,"John");
```

Don't forget to use malloc for the surname and name because the struct only contains pointers

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels: 1. You can't use `people` as a type without `typedef`ing it. 2. [Don't cast](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/249237) the result of `malloc`. 3. There is no mention of `struct liste`. 4. You mention arrays yet there are none here.

Comment: why? could you argue?

Comment: I am not sure about (people *) part because it gave me a error are you sure?

Comment: fixed the major problems, sorry for this

Comment: `new char[20]` isn't valid C. Also, your `typedef` is incomplete.